# How can you use ContextualMenu with Persona in Office Fabric UI React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-fabric

I am using [Office Fabric UI React](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/). I want to create a `ContextualMenu` which is used with the `Persona` object.

---

> This example directly uses ContextualMenu to show how it can be
>   attached to arbitrary elements. The remaining examples use
>   ContextualMenu through Fabric Button components.

Microsoft provides an example of how to apply a `ContextualMenu` to any arbitrary object, however, it does not seem to work with the `Persona` object. The `Persona` component does not have a `ref` property, and assigning the reference to the `componentRef` property does not seem to work.

It does seem that the `Persona` component has a property inherited from the `HTMLAttributes<T>` interface: `contextMenu?: string;`, but I don't see how an optional string can be used with `ContextualMenu`.

```
const AppHeaderProfile: React.FunctionComponent<IAppHeaderProfileProps> = () => {
  const personaRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [showContextualMenu, setShowContextualMenu] = React.useState(false);
  const onShowContextualMenu = useConstCallback(() =>
    setShowContextualMenu(true)
  );
  const onHideContextualMenu = useConstCallback(() =>
    setShowContextualMenu(false)
  );

  const menuItems: IContextualMenuItem[] = [
    {
      key: "profile",
      text: "My Profile",
      onclick: () => console.log("My Profile clicked")
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="app-header-profile">
      <Persona
        className="user"
        componentRef={personaRef}
        size={PersonaSize.size32}
        onClick={onShowContextualMenu}
      />
      <ContextualMenu
        items={menuItems}
        target={personaRef}
        hidden={!showContextualMenu}
        onItemClick={onHideContextualMenu}
        onDismiss={onHideContextualMenu}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prop onRenderPrimaryText or any other `onRender` prop to render things of your own. Then you can style the button according to your needs.

```
<Persona
  {...examplePersona}
  onRenderPrimaryText={(props: IPersonaProps) => (
    <Button
      menuProps={{
        items: [
          { key: "1", text: "Option1" },
          { key: "2", text: "Option2" }
        ]
      }}
    >
      {props.text}
    </Button>
  )}
/>;
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I am getting a `Type '(props: IPersonaProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'IRenderFunction<IPersonaProps>'.` error.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it. It's actually `(props?: IPersonaProps) => ( ... )`. But, this seems to render a button next to the persona coin instead of simply making the persona coin work with `ContextualMenu`.

Comment: I ended up using `onRenderOptionalText` which doesn't seem to render the button (which is good), but the `ContextualMenu` pops up on the left side of the screen when my `Persona` is on the top right side. It's nowhere near the control.